# Data is displayed in the vue console but not returned to the web page

Tags: vue.js

FileUpload.vue

```
<template>
<div>
   <vue-dropzone
           :options="dropzoneOptions">      
      <div class="dropzone-custom-content" id="custom">
        <h3 class="dropzone-custom-title">Drag & Drop</h3>       
      </div>
   </vue-dropzone>
    <div>
        Content: {{testmsg}}
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import vue2Dropzone from "vue2-dropzone";
import 'vue2-dropzone/dist/vue2Dropzone.min.css'
export default {
    components: {
        vueDropzone: vue2Dropzone,
    },
    data() {
        return {
            dropzoneOptions: {
                url: 'http://localhost:5000/',
                method: "post",
                maxFiles: 1,
                thumbnailWidth: 300,
                maxFilesize: 500,
                success: function (file, responejson) {
                    this.msg = responejson
                    console.log(this.msg)
                    this.testmsg='Hi'
                    console.log(this.testmsg)
                },
```

console.log(this.testmsg)=>Hi

After uploading an image, the value Hi does not appear on the web.

Image attached.
The console window results and scenes do not appear on the web.

[image]

This is the console window result.

[image]

Content: No value appears.

Comment: Can you declare let $this = this. and then change this.testmsg to $this.testmsg

Comment: let $ this = this?
Where should I declare?

Comment: let $this= this put it inside your success function and then instead of using this change all inside the success function to $this.


Btw, you can also change it its not necessarily $this you can change it what ever you want.

Comment: @Renato Manalili Still no response

Comment: How did you render the testmsg? do you have vue dev tools? It can also help you see if testmsg has received data.

Comment: I wasn't at the console and asked a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `testmsg` property in `data`. It should be:

```
data: () => ({
    testmsg: '',
    dropzoneOptions: {
          // rest of your code
     }
})
```

Comment: ```success(file, responejson) {
                    this.msg = responejson
                    console.log(this.msg)
                }```

Comment: How can I return msg data from a drop zone?

Comment: It looks like what you want to do is move the dropzone stuff into a method, not in data.

Comment: Is that possible?

Comment: Is it possible to illustrate?
With success